# KSQLDB stream produces results when defined as INNER JOIN but got stuck when defined as FULL JOIN

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm joining two streams, DATABASES and APPLICATIONS with following definitions

DATABASE

```
"fields": [
                {
                    "name": "DATABASE_ROWKEY",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "fields": null,
                        "memberSchema": null
                    },
                    "type": "KEY"
                },
                {
                    "name": "LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "BIGINT",
                        "fields": null,
                        "memberSchema": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "JOINKEY",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "fields": null,
                        "memberSchema": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_DETAILS",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "STRUCT",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "DATABASE_NAME",
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "STRING",
                                    "fields": null,
                                    "memberSchema": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "BIGINT",
                                    "fields": null,
                                    "memberSchema": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "DATABASE_SERVER",
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "STRING",
                                    "fields": null,
                                    "memberSchema": null
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "DB_OPERATIONAL_STATUS",
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "STRING",
                                    "fields": null,
                                    "memberSchema": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "memberSchema": null
                    }
                }
            ]
```

APPLICATIONS

```
    "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "APPLICATION_ROWKEY",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "STRING",
                            "fields": null,
                            "memberSchema": null
                        },
                        "type": "KEY"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "BIGINT",
                            "fields": null,
                            "memberSchema": null
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "JOINKEY",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "STRING",
                            "fields": null,
                            "memberSchema": null
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "APP_DETAILS",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "STRUCT",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "name": "APPLICATION_NAME",
                                    "schema": {
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "fields": null,
                                        "memberSchema": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
                                    "schema": {
                                        "type": "BIGINT",
                                        "fields": null,
                                        "memberSchema": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "APPLICATION_SERVER",
                                    "schema": {
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "fields": null,
                                        "memberSchema": null
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "APP_OPERATIONAL_STATUS",
                                    "schema": {
                                        "type": "STRING",
                                        "fields": null,
                                        "memberSchema": null
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "memberSchema": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

when doing new stream as full join of two previous ones, I receive no records, but when changing full join to inner join, new stream produces results and shows me records with common column JOINKEY.

How is that possible? Whole join query stays the same, the only thing I replace FULL with INNER in the query statement.

I've checked new stream description and customer offset and log startoffset of -join-right-repartition have the same value.